# UWP: Template for custom control fails with "Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty' from the text" error

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to create a custom `ContentDialog` control.  My custom class likes:

```
public class ContentDialogEx : ContentDialog
{
    public string PrimaryButtonGlyph
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(PrimaryButtonGlyphProperty);
        set => SetValue(PrimaryButtonGlyphProperty, value);
    }

    public string SecondaryButtonGlyph
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(SecondaryButtonGlyphProperty);
        set => SetValue(SecondaryButtonGlyphProperty, value);
    }

    public string CloseButtonGlyph
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(CloseButtonGlyphProperty);
        set => SetValue(CloseButtonGlyphProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PrimaryButtonGlyphProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(PrimaryButtonGlyph), typeof(string), typeof(ContentDialogEx), new PropertyMetadata("&#xF13E;"));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondaryButtonGlyphProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SecondaryButtonGlyph), typeof(string), typeof(ContentDialogEx), new PropertyMetadata("&#xF13D;"));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseButtonGlyphProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CloseButtonGlyph), typeof(string), typeof(ContentDialogEx), new PropertyMetadata("&#xF13D;"));

    public ContentDialogEx()
    {
        Template = PrismUnityApplication.Current.Resources["ContentDialogExTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
    }
}
```

The control template looks like:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Xaml.Controls">

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ContentDialogExTemplate" TargetType="controls:ContentDialogEx">
    ...
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The contents of the control template are copied from the default template and I have confirmed this works when I apply it to a standard `ContentDialog`.

This compiles fine and I can run the app but when I instantiate the dialog and try to show it I get the following error:

```
Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty' from the text 'Background'. [Line: 163 Position: 33]
```

If I try setting the `TargetType` of the `ControlTemplate` to `ContentDialog` I get the same error but it cannot find my custom property `PrimaryButtonGlyph`.

It is like it cannot find properties on the base class but if this was a problem then very little would work.  What am I doing wrong?

(Target version: Windows 10, version 1803 (10.0; Build 17134), Min version: Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299))

EDIT: I've created a demo solution here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4y7jrtcw3ivkqy/StackOverflow53506051.zip?dl=0

Comment: We could not figure it out, could you share a mini sample that could reproduce this issue?

Comment: I've created a sample app here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4y7jrtcw3ivkqy/StackOverflow53506051.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you code, you want to make custom **Templated Control** that inherit `ContentDialog`. But you have not initialized the default style. You could custom `ContentDialog` with following steps.

Create new items with `Templated Control` template.

[image]

After the `ContentDialogTest.cs` class created, the project will generate `Generic.Xaml` file automatically.

[image]

Please copy your `ContentDialogExTemplate` to `Generic.Xaml` file. Please not I have modified custom content dialog name to `ContentDialogTest`.

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ContentDialogTest" >
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ContentDialogTest">
                <Border>
                   .........
                </Border>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then create the `DependencyProperty` in `ContentDialogTest` class. you will find the there is `this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ContentDialogTest);` in the default constructor method. And this line make sure the style could be initialized.

```
public sealed class ContentDialogTest : ContentDialog
{
    public ContentDialogTest()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ContentDialogTest);
    }
    public string PrimaryButtonGlyph
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(PrimaryButtonGlyphProperty);
        set => SetValue(PrimaryButtonGlyphProperty, value);
    }

    public string SecondaryButtonGlyph
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(SecondaryButtonGlyphProperty);
        set => SetValue(SecondaryButtonGlyphProperty, value);
    }

    public string CloseButtonGlyph
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(CloseButtonGlyphProperty);
        set => SetValue(CloseButtonGlyphProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PrimaryButtonGlyphProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
              (nameof(PrimaryButtonGlyph),
               typeof(string),
               typeof(ContentDialogTest),
               new PropertyMetadata("&#xF13E;"));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondaryButtonGlyphProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        (nameof(SecondaryButtonGlyph),
        typeof(string), typeof(ContentDialogTest),
        new PropertyMetadata("&#xF13D;"));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseButtonGlyphProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
             (nameof(CloseButtonGlyph),
              typeof(string),
              typeof(ContentDialogTest),
              new PropertyMetadata("&#xF13D;"));
}
```

**Usage**

```
private async void OnShowContentDialogExButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dialog = new ContentDialogTest
    {
        Title = "Demo",
        Content = new Dialog(),

        PrimaryButtonText = "Primary",
        SecondaryButtonText = "Secondary",
        CloseButtonText = "Close"
    };

    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

For better understanding, I have upload the [code sample](https://github.com/lcxxxc/Nich) to git hub.